# Надо сделать онлайн запись на приём и прикрутить её к календарю

Tags: php, api, яндекс-календарь

Есть необходимость сделать онлайн запись на приём и прикрутить её к календарю. Есть какие-то api или библиотеки для работы? Ничего не могу найти. Как с ним вообще работать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, api для календаря ни к чему, он и так работает по стандарту CalDAV.

> Синхронизация позволит вам просматривать и редактировать свои встречи на Яндекс.Календаре с  мобильного телефона через другие приложения-календари. Изменения, внесенные в других приложениях, будут переданы в Яндекс.Календарь при соединении с интернетом.
>   Календари синхронизируются по протоколу CalDAV.

Здесь [инструкция](https://yandex.ru/support/calendar-new/sync/sync-mobile.html) по настройкам подключения к серверу, а готовые библиотеки на разных языках программирования можно найти, например [для php](https://github.com/wvrzel/simpleCalDAV).